# Picking out nested components of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON formatted API `response` that takes the following form when I turn it into a dictionary using `json.loads(response)`:

```
{
  "stories" : [
    {
      "headline" : "some text",
      "summary" : [
        "some more text"
      ],
      "texts" : [ 
        {
          "title" : "even more text",
          "id" : "a number"
        },
        {
          "title" : "more text",
          "id" : "another number"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's call this dictionary `dict`.

I can access `stories` using `dict['stories']`. But how do I access the `summary` bit?

I thought I could do `dict['stories']['summary']` but that throws the error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Comment: `dict['stories'][0]['summary']`? BTW, it is not a good idea to name your variable same as a built-in function; in this case, `dict`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Because your `stories` is a `list`.

  **do this**

```
dict['stories'][0]['summary']
```

PS: One tip dont use `dict` as a variable. Its bad practice to use `keywords` as `variables`. You will run into issues that will haunt you in night. :)

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for the prompt reply! Quick follow-up: is there an easy way to drop the square brackets from the resulting `summary` item (i.e., `["some more text"]`)?

Comment: You can do `dict['stories'][0]['summary'][0]` to access element of list. :)